# report error when i use github desktop to upload my 1GB files

Tags: github, github-desktop

[error report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbt99.png)

I successfully uploaded 1KB file to my github,but failed to upload 1GB file.That is the error report image.what could i do?please don`t use git lfs,because it also report many error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the nature of git, where one typically downloads the complete history, large files are to be avoided. Especially large binaries: images, videos, and compressed files.

[GitHub blocks files larger than 100 MB](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files) and [suggests using git-lfs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files). If you're having trouble with git-lfs ask about that.

If the large file is a compressed archive like a .zip or .tgz, unarchive it and add its individual files. Git will then be able to version and compress them individually.